# Swagger codegen maven plugin - issue with some jersey imports

Tags: java, maven, jersey-2.0, importerror, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate client Api using the swagger codegen maven plugin, version 2.3.1.

But in my generated ApiClient.java, some jersey-related imports do not work. I think it has to do with the version of the jersey dependencies, but I cannot find a working solution to my problem, even after 2 days of searching and trying.

**How do I configure the plugin, or what dependencies must I add, so the generated code will work?**

not working imports (ApiClient.java):

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
```

swagger codegen plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger.json</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <modelPackage>somePackage.models</modelPackage>
                <apiPackage>somePackage.api</apiPackage>
                <invokerPackage>somePackage.invoker</invokerPackage>
                <configOptions>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    <sourceFolder>swagger</sourceFolder>
                    <java8>true</java8>
                </configOptions>
                <library>jersey2</library>
                <output>target/generated-sources</output>
                <groupId>somePackage</groupId>
                <artifactId>generatedapi</artifactId>
                <artifactVersion>1.0.0</artifactVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I change the version to 2.27 then additional imports fail to work:
`import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;`

When I change the version to 2.26 then the same additional imports fail, but
`import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;` works.

Answer (score 0):

When trying it out today, it just worked. No matter what jersey version i use.

I guess it had something to do with some caching of my IDE or so. I'm quite confused, but happy that it works now.